# Thunderbird mail client mark of inbox mail unread to read?

Tags: thunderbird

I am using thunderbird mail client for gmail accounts,Its works fine,enjoying functionality too. I have problem with this mail client that is when I client inbox its has list of unread mails,once viewed it. its become read mail. thats not happening gmail servers.if login in gmail i m still finding unread mails which i read in thuderbird.

Please help me how to solve these problem, is there any option or setttings or addons which change status of mail when I read it.

Thanks & Regards

kumar kasimala.

Hyderabad,India.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How does Thunderbird sync with Gmail? If it's using POP3, then the emails will not be marked as read. POP3 simply makes copies of the emails for thunderbird, then leaves the originals on the server (or deletes them if you have that enabled).

If that's the case, you should set up Thunderbird to use IMAP. This will keep Thunderbird in sync with your Gmail account. (They have a specific page in their help files for doing this If I recall correctly)

Comment: Hi Darth Android thanks, can you help to setup IMAP in thuderbird.

Comment: @kumar kasimala http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=77662